# How to access friend of friends photos in Ruby on rails with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I have a one User A and I can access the data of user A like friends list,photos,video,etc.
and also get information about user A's friends(like user B) like friends list,photos,video,etc.But when I try to access the user B friends photos it give me nil array.

Anyone can have an idea about how to access friend of friends photos in facebook?

Thanks,
Nishit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You cannot access information about friend of friends.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/